# Declared object in a constant only with the exact properties defined in the type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, jsdoc

We’re using typescript together with JSDoc in our JS based application, only to define the types of the parameters we use in our functions.
In a specific case we want to have objects with a defined structure, and we need to ensure that every object declared under certain type only has the expected properties

```
type Keys = 'foo' | 'bar';

type Things = {
  [K in Keys]: Thing;
}

interface Thing {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

When creating an object of type `Things` I would expect this to have ONLY the attributes defined in `Thing`

```
const object = /** @type {Things} */ ({
  foo: { a: 'foo_a', b: 'foo_b' },
  bar: { a: 'bar_a', b: 'bar_b' }
})
```

But practically, we can declare a property `abc` without any complain by Typescript. It’ll only complain if, when trying to access the properties of that object, we call a property that does not exist on the type declaration. For example, if we do `object.abc` it will complain.

### Error

As you would imagine, this will trigger an error:

```
object.abc // abc is not defined in type Things
```

### No Errors

Adding the `abc` which is not defined in the Type, does **not** trigger an TS error:

```
const object = /** @type {Things} */ ({
  foo: { a: 'foo_a', b: 'foo_b' },
  bar: { a: 'bar_a', b: 'bar_b' },
  abc: { a: 'abc_a', b: 'abc_b' },
})
```

I’d like to prevent the declaration of non-defined in type properties when creating the object of type `Things`.

### Playground

[TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Keys%20%3D%20'foo'%20%7C%20'bar'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Things%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20Keys%5D%3A%20Thing%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Thing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20object%20%3D%20%2F**%20%40type%20%7BThings%7D%20*%2F%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20'foo_a'%2C%20b%3A%20'foo_b'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20'bar_a'%2C%20b%3A%20'bar_b'%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20abc%3A%20%7B%20a%3A%20'abc_a'%2C%20b%3A%20'abc_b'%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20This%20shouldn't%20be%20allowed.%20Not%20defined%20in%20Keys%20%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0Aobject.xyz%20%2F%2F%20Property%20'xyz'%20is%20not%20defined%20in%20type%20)

**Anyone faced any similar issue?**

Thank you

Comment: `const object: Things = ...` seems to work as expected

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thank you, it would work if we were using ".ts" files but we're using ".js" files.

Answer (score 0):

As @ExplosionPills says, in:

```
const object = /** @type {Things} */ ({
    foo: { a: 'foo_a', b: 'foo_b' },
    bar: { a: 'bar_a', b: 'bar_b' },
    abc: { a: 'abc_a', b: 'abc_b' } // This shouldn't be allowed. Not defined in Keys 
})
```

"object" is not defined as a type "Things", hence it does not error as object is implicitly of type any, so you can assign whatever you want to it.

You need to change your code to:

```
const object : Things = /** @type {Things} */ ({
    foo: { a: 'foo_a', b: 'foo_b' },
    bar: { a: 'bar_a', b: 'bar_b' },
    abc: { a: 'abc_a', b: 'abc_b' } // This will now be highlighted as an error 
})
```

Doing this only then allows objects of type Things to be assigned to object. Once you make this change you will then see Typescript complain about the error.

Comment: Thanks! We're not using .ts files, thus we can't use this solution.

We're using TypeScript with JSDocs. We only use ".ts" files for defining the interfaces.

Not sure if there's a way around this.

Comment: Adding ":Things" is just like you have done for defining a string i.e. ":string", so why cant you use this? Without adding ":Things" your code is doing exactly as its asked i.e. creating a javascript object of type any.

Comment: The object is created in a .JS file while the interface is crated in a .TS file.
I guess our setup with JSDocs doesn't allow this. Thanks for the input Ben.

Comment: No problems @Ricard , hope you find a solution.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? @Ricard

Comment: @rnarcos It's been 3 years, I can't recall. Sorry.